# Unable to generate and download pdf after shifting the website on Cloud - Application Server OS - Windows Server 2012

Tags: asp.net, .net, itext

We generate pdf certificates for our users through itextsharp namespace in the dot net 3.5 application platform which we are using. Now after we have shifted our website to cloud (earlier it was on shared hosting) the website is not generating the pdf. Although it is working on our localhost on our Windows 8 computer and was also working on the earlier shared hosting server.

Only after we have shifted to Cloud on (Application Server OS - Windows Server 2012, Database Server OS - Windows Server 2012 R2) that is has stopped generating pdf and we are unable to click or download the pdf icon.

Help from experts is requested for this issue.

Comment: Are you a paying customer? If so, please post this question on the closed ticketing system as indicated in your support contract. If not, then you are using iText under the AGPL. In that case, you should also release your own code as open source software. In that case, please give us a link to your source code.

Comment: My issue is that everything(pdf is generating) is working fine on localhost but not on cloud. Could you please guide on this.